# How can I rescue broken filenames?

Tags: linux, encoding

Apparently, someone didn't pay attention to the encoding when moving files from one server to another and I ended up with filenames containing German umlauts that appear as question mark in `ls` when using PuTTY. However, when using bash autocomplete, the filename is not displayed with a question mark but with a weird character instead. FileZilla on the other hand displays the characters correctly via SFTP (SSH, not FTP with SSL/TLS) in the file list, but cannot transfer the files:

```
/var/www/domain.tld/Maße.doc: open for read: no such file or directory
```

With `ls` I get:

```
-rw-r-----   1 smares smares  19K May  9  2013 Ma?e.doc
```

And when hitting tab to autocomplete:

```
smares@smares:/var/www/domain.tld$ cat Ma▒e.doc
```

Is there any way I can rescue the filenames?

Comment: How is the locale set up in your system and your shell in particular.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint. While I had locales generated for UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 and also tried with both as LANG, I didn't switch the remote character encoding in PuTTY. With that set to ISO-8859-1 and LANG being set to de_DE.ISO-8859-1, it works. :)

Comment: I would try to use utf-8 from now on. That way you can mix languages, and not have to reconfigure terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to switch the remote character set in PuTTY to ISO-8859-1, have locales generated for de_DE.ISO-8859-1 and use that as LANG.